# Python XOR behavior with a mix of positive/negative number

Tags: python, bit, xor

Here is two results I get when I xor 2 integers. The sames bits, but a different sign for the second parameter of the xor.

```
>>> bin(0b0001 ^ -0b0010)
'-0b1'
>>> bin(0b0001 ^  0b0010)
'0b11'
```

I don't really understand the logic. Isn't XOR just supposed so XOR every bit one by one ? Even with signed bits ? I would expect to get the same results (with a different sign).

Comment: You can think of it as xor of the bits of the numbers in 2's complement form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If python's integers were fixed-width (eg: 32-bit, or 64-bit), a negative number would be represented in 2's complement form. That is, if you want `-a`, then take the bits of `a`, invert them all, and then add 1. Then `a ^ b` is just the number that's represented by the bitwise xor of the bits of `a` and `b` in two's complement. The result is re-interpreted in two's complement (ie: negative if the top bit is set).

Python's `int` type isn't fixed-width, but the result of `a ^ b` follows the same pattern: imagine that the values are represented as a wide-enough fixed-with int type, and then take the xor of the two values.

Although this now seems a bit arbitrary, it makes sense historically: Python adopted many operations from C, so xor was defined to work like in C. Python had a fixed-width integer type like C, and having `a ^ b` give the same result for the fixed-width and arbitary-width integer types essentially forces the current definition.

Back to a worked example: `1 ^ -2`. 8 bits is more than enough to represent these two values. In 2's complement:

```
 1 = 00000001
-2 = 11111110
```

Then the bitwise xor is:

```
   = 11111111
```

This is the 8-bit 2's complement representation of -1. Although we've used 8 bits here, the result is the same no matter the width chosen as long as it's enough to represent the two values.

Comment: Oh, I think I'm starting to see what I missing. -0b0010 in python is not the right form, the 2 complement, on which the XOR is really applied, and thus the XOR is not really working on what I see here?

Comment: Yes, you have to think that the bits of `-2` (or whatever value you have) are what they'd be in 2's complement form for some wide-enough integer type.